# Where can I find the default path for a tablespace if I did not specify one

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

So I created a tablespace without specifying path. What do I do in this case.Somewhat related but how do I create a n Sql script on Sql dev?

[image: 1]

I tried creating a path after that but I couldn't

Answer (score 2):

It will get created under whatever path the parameter `db_create_file_dest` specifies.

In SQL Plus, type `show parameter db_create_file_dest` or query `v$parameter`.

If that parameter is not defined, it should create it in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` , which you probably don't want it to do.